# LanguageTool : words followed by word different from

Tags: regex, xml, languagetool

How can I match a series of words followed by a word different from `x`?

For instance, how can I match `at the cost of` followed by a word different from `some`?

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
<rule id="AT_THE_COST_OF_!SOME" name="at the cost of !some">
<pattern>
<token>at</token>
<token>the</token>
<token>cost</token>
<token>of</token>
<token regexp="yes">/^((?!some).)*$</token>
</pattern>
<message>Did you mean <suggestion>at the cost of some \5</suggestion>?</message>
<example correction='at the cost of some efforts'>Yes, it comes 
<marker>at the cost of efforts</marker>.</example>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LanguageTool works on tokens. Using regexp is a special case and if using regexp, they work on single tokens (when using `pattern`). This will solve your problem:

```
<pattern>
    <token>at</token>
    <token>the</token>
    <token>cost</token>
    <token>of</token>
    <token><exception>some</exception></token>
</pattern>
```

To use regular expressions anyway, use `<regexp>` as documented at http://wiki.languagetool.org/development-overview#toc8.

Comment: Building on your answer, a possible complete `LanguageTool` entry would be `<rule id="AT_THE_COST_OF_!SOME" name="at the cost of !some">
 <pattern>
 <token>at</token>
 <token>the</token>
 <token>cost</token>
 <token>of</token>
 <token><exception>some</exception></token>
 </pattern>
 <message>Did you mean <suggestion>at the cost of some \5</suggestion>?</message>
 <example correction='at the cost of some efforts'>Yes, it comes 
 <marker>at the cost of efforts</marker>.</example>
 </rule>`

Answer (score 0):

Traditional regular expressions can also be used by using `<regexp>` tag instead of using `<token>` tag. ( But requires LanguageTool 3.2 or later for using `<regexp>`). For more info - [wiki](http://wiki.languagetool.org/development-overview)

`<regexp>(at the cost of (?!some\b))\w+<regexp>`

**Patterns matched:**

> at the cost of someone
>
> at the cost of everything

**Pattern discarded:**

> at the cost of some

Please test it [here](http://regexr.com/3diah)

Comment: Thanks. The test work but I am still struggling to include it in LanguageTool. In particular, the rule `<rule id="AT_THE_COST_OF_!SOME" name="at the cost of !some">
 <pattern>
 <token regexp="yes">/(at the cost of (?!some\b))\w+/</token>
 </pattern>
 <message>Did you mean <suggestion>at the cost of some</suggestion>?</message>
 <example correction='at the cost of some'>Yes, it comes 
 <marker>at the cost of efforts</marker>.</example>
 </rule>    ` does not work when I use `LanguageTool` with `Texstudio`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, I would ideally want a rule that allows to suggest a correction of the form `at the cost of some \w+`, that is including the word that was originally proposed after `of`.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden, I am glad that it helped. Since you know the regex to be used, I suggest posting a new question with the problem you are facing along with the new requirements so that you get your problem solved.

Comment: Using regular expressions that span several tokens will only work when using  `<regexp>`, not when using `<pattern>`. Even then, the `/` are not part of the regex. `<pattern>` should be preferred.